# Why does not noise accumulate in a stochastic differential equation as it would in a random walk?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I had a question about stochastic differential equations. I come from statistics, so I am more familiar with say random walks, which are of course, discrete. So if I had a process like where $x(t)$ traces the random walk evolution of a variable over time, then that might look like this recursively:

$$
x(t+1) = x(t) + \epsilon \sim Binomial(p,n)
$$

where $p,n$ are parameters for the chance of success and number of trials, respectively. If I ran this simulation multiple and plotted time $t$ versus $x(t)$, I would get a fan or cone shaped plot with all trajectories starting at the same point, but then progressively spreading out with each time step.

My question is, when I look at plots of stochastic differential equations, I don't see this same kind of fanning behavior. When talking about an SDE of the form:

$$
du = f(u, p, t)dt + g(u, p, t)dW
$$

In this case, $f$ is the deterministic part of the process and $g$ is the noise process, usually Brownian motion. This is of course a continuous time equation. Here is a plot of a stochastic version of the lorenz equation that conforms to the SDE form above--taken from the [Julia Differential Equations documentation](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/sde_example/#Example-2:-Systems-of-SDEs-with-Diagonal-Noise).

[image: Stochastic Lorenz System]

Again, my question is, why don't we see the trajectory fan out over time. It seems like the trajectory does wiggle, but it does not diffuse as in a random walk. I was just trying to understand what are the forces at play that prevent the noise process to overwhelm the deterministic part of the process over time?

Comment: You could also give the source of the image, as that contains the concrete system: https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/sde_example/#Example-2:-Systems-of-SDEs-with-Diagonal-Noise

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes thanks for the reminder. I included the link to the source in the question now, no worries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chaotic attractor of the Lorenz system is, as the name says, attracting. Thus any deviation introduced by the stochastic term is corrected towards the double spiral.

One still gets a trajectory fan if one starts at the same point and computes and plots several paths with different random walks. Again, any deviation from the plane or surface of the single spirals will be quickly corrected, the random movements spread and accumulate majorly inside that surface.

[image: start at 5,5,5, time to 2]

<sub>*Above for the initial segment $t\in[0,2]$ after the start at $(x,y,z)=(5,5,5)$, below a little more evolution with $t\in[0,6]$.*</sub>

[image: the same, time to 6]

As one can see, in the outer rim of the spirals, away from their intersection where the velocity of the Lorenz system is high the paths are almost smooth, while in the slower inner parts the noise terms have more influence. As was constructed, as the random motion increments are merely added to the velocity vector.

The bundle of trajectories visibly dissolves with the first change to the other spiral. The inane chaotic nature of the Lorenz system magnifies the deviations due to the accumulated random increments.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation--very helpful. This makes sense in the context of a Lorenz system where the attractor will compress he deviations and hence the trajectory looks more under control. But even if I were to have something without an attractor--say a simple SDE growth equation $du = k*u + g(u)dW$, would I still get large deviations or a big fan over time?

Comment: I get that with brownian motion, the variance of the noise is a function of the length of the timestep (when the equation is discretized or even in the measure theoretic sense), but even then it still seems like the trajectories don't deform as much as I would expect when compared to a random walk. Of course random walks and SDEs are opposite ends of the spectrum, but just trying to bridge my understanding of random walks to less familiar SDEs.

Comment: Do not forget that with $k=0$ and $g(u)=1$ you get the Brownian motion back. But as said, most of it is due to the motion towards an attractor. If $k$ is negative, then $0$ would be stable in the smooth dynamic and all paths will meander around the zero position.

Comment: Okay great. I will probably just run some experiments with the Julia SDE solver to get a feel for the variability. But your explanation helps to give me some context before just running some blind experiments. Thanks again for your help.